# Tag Input with typing disabled only?

Tags: reactjs, blueprintjs

I want to use the Tag Input within my web app, but I want to forbid users from adding new tags, but still retaining the functionality of removing tags.

The application should be able to add tags dynamically via a separate process, and then users can remove those tags if they want to, but they should NOT be able to type in the input field to add their own tags.

Is this possible? I know you can set the whole Tag Input to disabled, but this also removes the ability to remove tags - which I want to retain.

Comment: huh yeah seems this specific case is not supported in the code currently. file an issue on GitHub and we can address it!

Comment: I have the same use case, I want to have a multi select without a search, and just show the tags from selected options, seems there is no way?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried disabling the underlying `input` itself rather than the `TagInput`? Something like:

```js
<TagInput
    ...
    inputProps={{
        disabled: true
    }}
/>
```

Comment: @JavascriptLoser Ah, I took a look at the source and unfortunately `inputProps.disabled` isn't passed into the underlying `input`. A suggestion: simply iterate through your list of tags and render a `Tag` component for each one. It's probably not much longer code-wise and you don't need all the overhead of an input regardless.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option call inputFieldPosition; not sure about its valid values but by setting `inputFieldPosition = {'none'}`, you can hide input and still can have delete and drag feature available if you want.